# Как масштабировать элементы SVG изображения

Tags: html, svg, дизайн, позиционирование

Есть блок на сайте, с достаточно сложной компоновкой. На столе, есть блюда, с заранее определенными координатами на "холсте". При наведении на блюдо, происходит scale, а при нажатии, появляется блок с информацией, и все остальное пространство, затемняется.
Вот как это должно выглядеть: https://yadi.sk/i/tMIaCVePwAbO4w

Загвоздка в следующем: При hover, я указываю: `transform: scale(1.2)` элементу `<rect/>`, на котором висит изображение блюда. И оно увеличивается, однако смещается в правый нижний угол. Ставлю `transform-origin`, по разному, но результата нет. Мне нужно, чтобы `<rect/>`, масштабировался из центра(

```html
<style>
  .block {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  svg {
    width: 100%
  }
</style>

<div class="block">
  <svg width="1440" height="790" viewBox="0 0 1440 790" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
        <style>
            #item6 {
                transform-origin: left center;
                transition: all .2s;
                z-index: 99999;
            }
            #item6:hover {
                transform: translate(-107.2px, -43.9px) scale(1);
            }
        </style>
        <rect width="1440" height="790" fill="none"/>
        <rect id="dark" width="1440" height="790" fill="black" fill-opacity="0.5"/>
        <rect id="dark-bottom" y="637" width="1440" height="153" fill="url(#paint0_linear)"/>
        <g id="birthday">
            <g id="group6">
                <rect id="item6" x="1072" y="541" width="245" height="249" fill="url(#pattern0)"/>
                <g id="info_6">
                    <g id="arrow6">
                        <path id="line6" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd"
                              d="M760 653.5C760 652.395 760.895 651.5 762 651.5H1023.28L1206.56 704.579C1207.62 704.886 1208.23 705.995 1207.92 707.056C1207.61 708.117 1206.5 708.728 1205.44 708.421L1022.72 655.5H762C760.895 655.5 760 654.605 760 653.5Z"
                              fill="white"/>
                        <path id="ellipse6"
                              d="M1222 706.5C1222 715.613 1214.61 723 1205.5 723C1196.39 723 1189 715.613 1189 706.5C1189 697.387 1196.39 690 1205.5 690C1214.61 690 1222 697.387 1222 706.5Z"
                              fill="#F32121"/>
                        <path id="ellipseStroke6" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd"
                              d="M1205.5 692.5C1197.77 692.5 1191.5 698.768 1191.5 706.5C1191.5 714.232 1197.77 720.5 1205.5 720.5C1213.23 720.5 1219.5 714.232 1219.5 706.5C1219.5 698.768 1213.23 692.5 1205.5 692.5ZM1186.5 706.5C1186.5 696.007 1195.01 687.5 1205.5 687.5C1215.99 687.5 1224.5 696.007 1224.5 706.5C1224.5 716.993 1215.99 725.5 1205.5 725.5C1195.01 725.5 1186.5 716.993 1186.5 706.5Z"
                              fill="white"/>
                    </g>
                    <g id="infBlock6_2">
                        <path id="text6_2_1"
                              d="M795.704 681.392H797.112V670.4H796.344L793.752 671.6V672.416L795.704 671.984V681.392ZM803.947 681.52C806.139 681.52 807.867 680.048 807.867 676.368V675.44C807.867 671.696 806.091 670.384 803.963 670.384C801.819 670.384 799.947 671.696 799.947 675.504V676.352C799.947 680.016 801.691 681.52 803.947 681.52ZM803.947 680.368C802.299 680.368 801.451 679.104 801.451 676.464V675.328C801.451 672.688 802.331 671.536 803.963 671.536C805.563 671.536 806.411 672.752 806.411 675.44V676.544C806.411 679.28 805.547 680.368 803.947 680.368ZM809.848 676.72H815.112V675.552H809.848V676.72ZM817.813 681.392H819.221V670.4H818.453L815.861 671.6V672.416L817.813 671.984V681.392ZM824.504 681.52C826.872 681.52 828.312 679.904 828.312 677.968C828.312 675.696 826.984 674.64 824.824 674.64C824.36 674.64 823.736 674.752 823.32 674.864L823.528 671.728H827.896V670.56H822.408L822.024 676.256C822.52 676.032 823.528 675.728 824.264 675.728C825.896 675.728 826.856 676.352 826.856 677.936C826.856 679.424 825.864 680.352 824.2 680.352C823.336 680.352 822.328 679.984 821.736 679.6L821.464 680.72C822.12 681.168 823.256 681.52 824.504 681.52ZM833.891 681.136H835.251L835.443 677.504C835.491 676.672 835.539 675.648 835.555 674.72H835.603C835.811 675.44 836.131 676.576 836.387 677.296L837.731 681.104H838.803L840.259 677.232C840.691 676.032 840.899 675.424 841.123 674.72H841.155C841.187 675.648 841.251 676.656 841.283 677.472L841.475 681.136H842.867L842.323 673.392H840.499L839.283 676.736C838.979 677.584 838.563 678.784 838.371 679.36H838.355C838.163 678.736 837.859 677.808 837.651 677.248L836.275 673.392H834.467L833.891 681.136ZM844.636 673.392V681.136H846.348C847.148 679.792 847.98 678.32 848.7 677.104C849.148 676.336 849.468 675.728 849.964 674.736H849.996C849.932 676.016 849.9 676.64 849.9 677.904V681.136H851.308V673.392H849.58L847.228 677.36C846.7 678.256 846.46 678.8 845.98 679.744L845.932 679.728C845.996 678.608 846.028 677.84 846.028 676.592V673.392H844.636ZM853.542 673.392V681.136H854.998V677.664H858.598V681.136H860.07V673.392H858.598V676.512H854.998V673.392H853.542ZM861.332 673.328L864.18 679.872C864.26 680.032 864.292 680.144 864.292 680.224C864.292 680.32 864.244 680.4 864.18 680.56C863.844 681.232 863.38 681.664 863.012 681.952C862.58 682.288 862.116 682.512 861.78 682.608L862.212 683.728C862.628 683.616 863.412 683.296 864.036 682.784C864.964 681.968 865.572 680.864 866.58 678.304L868.676 673.328H867.108L865.604 677.504C865.428 678.016 865.299 678.448 865.124 678.88H865.076C864.932 678.448 864.772 678 864.58 677.52L862.932 673.328H861.332ZM868.957 673.392V674.544H871.357V681.136H872.829V674.544H875.229V673.392H868.957Z"
                              fill="white"/>
                        <g id="clock" clip-path="url(#clip0)">
                            <g id="XMLID 806">
                                <g id="XMLID 386">
                                    <path id="XMLID 389"
                                          d="M783.958 676.016C783.76 674.029 782.872 672.156 781.458 670.742C780.249 669.533 778.77 668.757 777.214 668.411V667.32C777.849 667.161 778.322 666.586 778.322 665.902C778.322 665.096 777.667 664.441 776.861 664.441H773.767C772.962 664.441 772.306 665.096 772.306 665.902C772.306 666.586 772.779 667.161 773.414 667.32V668.414C771.863 668.761 770.388 669.537 769.183 670.742C768.919 671.006 768.676 671.282 768.453 671.57C768.443 671.569 768.432 671.568 768.421 671.568H765.359C765.122 671.568 764.929 671.761 764.929 671.998C764.929 672.235 765.122 672.428 765.359 672.428H767.869C767.554 672.955 767.3 673.509 767.106 674.079H762.43C762.192 674.079 762 674.272 762 674.509C762 674.746 762.192 674.939 762.43 674.939H766.863C766.74 675.482 766.669 676.036 766.65 676.59H764.75C764.513 676.59 764.32 676.783 764.32 677.02C764.32 677.257 764.513 677.45 764.75 677.45H766.664C766.7 678.006 766.79 678.559 766.932 679.101H764.148C763.911 679.101 763.719 679.294 763.719 679.531C763.719 679.768 763.911 679.961 764.148 679.961H767.206C767.628 681.076 768.287 682.121 769.183 683.017C770.599 684.433 772.474 685.321 774.463 685.517C774.746 685.545 775.03 685.559 775.314 685.559C776.991 685.559 778.646 685.074 780.051 684.159C780.25 684.03 780.306 683.763 780.177 683.565C780.047 683.366 779.781 683.309 779.582 683.439C776.507 685.441 772.389 685.008 769.791 682.41C766.741 679.36 766.741 674.399 769.791 671.35C772.84 668.301 777.801 668.301 780.85 671.35C783.446 673.945 783.881 678.059 781.885 681.133C781.756 681.332 781.813 681.598 782.012 681.727C782.211 681.856 782.477 681.8 782.606 681.601C783.672 679.959 784.152 677.975 783.958 676.016ZM773.166 665.902C773.166 665.57 773.435 665.3 773.767 665.3H776.861C777.193 665.3 777.463 665.57 777.463 665.902C777.463 666.234 777.193 666.503 776.861 666.503H776.784H773.844H773.767C773.435 666.503 773.166 666.234 773.166 665.902ZM774.274 668.267V667.363H776.354V668.265C775.663 668.183 774.965 668.183 774.274 668.267Z"
                                          fill="white"/>
                                    <path id="XMLID 391"
                                          d="M781.154 682.284C781.041 682.284 780.93 682.33 780.851 682.41C780.77 682.49 780.725 682.6 780.725 682.713C780.725 682.826 780.77 682.937 780.851 683.017C780.93 683.098 781.041 683.143 781.154 683.143C781.267 683.143 781.378 683.098 781.458 683.017C781.538 682.937 781.584 682.826 781.584 682.713C781.584 682.6 781.538 682.49 781.458 682.41C781.378 682.33 781.267 682.284 781.154 682.284Z"
                                          fill="white"/>
                                    <path id="XMLID 394"
                                          d="M775.321 670.214C771.645 670.214 768.655 673.204 768.655 676.88C768.655 680.555 771.645 683.545 775.321 683.545C778.996 683.545 781.986 680.555 781.986 676.88C781.986 673.204 778.996 670.214 775.321 670.214ZM775.321 682.686C772.119 682.686 769.514 680.081 769.514 676.88C769.514 673.678 772.119 671.073 775.321 671.073C778.522 671.073 781.127 673.678 781.127 676.88C781.127 680.081 778.522 682.686 775.321 682.686Z"
                                          fill="white"/>
                                    <path id="XMLID 397"
                                          d="M778.038 673.554L775.91 675.682C775.732 675.594 775.532 675.544 775.32 675.544C775.109 675.544 774.908 675.594 774.73 675.682L773.778 674.729C773.61 674.562 773.338 674.562 773.17 674.729C773.002 674.897 773.002 675.169 773.17 675.337L774.123 676.289C774.035 676.467 773.985 676.668 773.985 676.879C773.985 677.616 774.584 678.215 775.32 678.215C776.057 678.215 776.656 677.616 776.656 676.879C776.656 676.668 776.606 676.467 776.518 676.289L778.584 674.224L778.646 674.161C778.814 673.993 778.814 673.721 778.646 673.554C778.478 673.386 778.206 673.386 778.038 673.554ZM775.32 677.355C775.058 677.355 774.844 677.142 774.844 676.879C774.844 676.617 775.058 676.403 775.32 676.403C775.583 676.403 775.796 676.617 775.796 676.879C775.796 677.142 775.583 677.355 775.32 677.355Z"
                                          fill="white"/>
                                    <path id="XMLID 398"
                                          d="M779.915 676.455H779.517C779.279 676.455 779.087 676.647 779.087 676.885C779.087 677.122 779.279 677.314 779.517 677.314H779.915C780.152 677.314 780.344 677.122 780.344 676.885C780.344 676.647 780.152 676.455 779.915 676.455Z"
                                          fill="white"/>
                                    <path id="XMLID 399"
                                          d="M771.124 676.445H770.726C770.489 676.445 770.296 676.637 770.296 676.875C770.296 677.112 770.489 677.304 770.726 677.304H771.124C771.361 677.304 771.554 677.112 771.554 676.875C771.554 676.637 771.361 676.445 771.124 676.445Z"
                                          fill="white"/>
                                    <path id="XMLID 400"
                                          d="M775.326 673.113C775.563 673.113 775.755 672.921 775.755 672.683V672.285C775.755 672.048 775.563 671.855 775.326 671.855C775.088 671.855 774.896 672.048 774.896 672.285V672.683C774.896 672.921 775.088 673.113 775.326 673.113Z"
                                          fill="white"/>
                                    <path id="XMLID 424"
                                          d="M775.315 680.646C775.078 680.646 774.886 680.838 774.886 681.076V681.474C774.886 681.711 775.078 681.903 775.315 681.903C775.553 681.903 775.745 681.711 775.745 681.474V681.076C775.745 680.838 775.553 680.646 775.315 680.646Z"
                                          fill="white"/>
                                    <path id="XMLID 425"
                                          d="M762.43 679.101C762.317 679.101 762.206 679.147 762.126 679.227C762.046 679.307 762 679.418 762 679.531C762 679.644 762.046 679.755 762.126 679.835C762.206 679.914 762.317 679.96 762.43 679.96C762.543 679.96 762.654 679.914 762.733 679.835C762.813 679.755 762.859 679.644 762.859 679.531C762.859 679.418 762.813 679.307 762.733 679.227C762.654 679.147 762.543 679.101 762.43 679.101Z"
                                          fill="white"/>
                                </g>
                            </g>
                        </g>
                    </g>
                    <g id="infoBlock6_1">
                        <path id="text6_1_1"
                              d="M772.98 632.92L768.8 626.02L772.86 619.42H770.76L768.98 622.54C768.48 623.44 768.16 624.04 767.78 624.84H767.72C767.36 624.1 767 623.44 766.5 622.54L764.72 619.42H762.64L766.58 626.1L762.46 632.92H764.58L766.18 630C766.84 628.84 767.22 628.1 767.6 627.32H767.64C768.06 628.1 768.46 628.86 769.16 630L770.86 632.92H772.98ZM774.865 623.24V632.92H777.005C778.005 631.24 779.045 629.4 779.945 627.88C780.505 626.92 780.905 626.16 781.525 624.92H781.565C781.485 626.52 781.445 627.3 781.445 628.88V632.92H783.205V623.24H781.045L778.105 628.2C777.445 629.32 777.145 630 776.545 631.18L776.485 631.16C776.565 629.76 776.605 628.8 776.605 627.24V623.24H774.865ZM785.998 623.24V632.92H787.818V628.58H792.318V632.92H794.158V623.24H792.318V627.14H787.818V623.24H785.998ZM796.995 623.24V632.92H798.835V628.7H799.155C800.755 628.7 801.655 629.4 802.295 630.94C802.595 631.76 802.915 632.52 803.195 632.92H805.115C804.655 632.14 804.335 631.18 804.075 630.54C803.315 628.8 802.395 627.78 800.835 627.6L805.035 623.24H802.795L799.215 627.44H798.835V623.24H796.995ZM813.543 627C813.543 625.04 812.803 623.02 809.803 623.02C808.543 623.02 807.363 623.38 806.583 623.86L806.983 625.08C807.663 624.64 808.603 624.38 809.523 624.38C811.503 624.36 811.703 625.78 811.703 626.56V626.74C807.983 626.7 805.903 628 805.903 630.36C805.903 631.76 806.923 633.16 808.863 633.16C810.243 633.16 811.303 632.48 811.823 631.72H811.883L812.023 632.92H813.703C813.583 632.26 813.543 631.44 813.543 630.62V627ZM811.743 629.66C811.743 629.82 811.743 630.04 811.663 630.22C811.383 631 810.603 631.8 809.363 631.8C808.483 631.8 807.743 631.28 807.743 630.14C807.743 628.32 809.843 627.96 811.743 628V629.66ZM816.91 623.24V627.1C816.91 629.24 816.79 630.58 815.91 631.22C815.67 631.42 815.29 631.58 814.93 631.64L815.13 633.08C816.05 633.08 816.63 632.86 817.11 632.46C818.35 631.62 818.61 629.82 818.61 627.12V624.68H821.87V632.92H823.71V623.24H816.91ZM826.486 623.24V632.92H828.626C829.626 631.24 830.666 629.4 831.566 627.88C832.126 626.92 832.526 626.16 833.146 624.92H833.186C833.106 626.52 833.066 627.3 833.066 628.88V632.92H834.826V623.24H832.666L829.726 628.2C829.066 629.32 828.766 630 828.166 631.18L828.106 631.16C828.186 629.76 828.226 628.8 828.226 627.24V623.24H826.486ZM845.493 622.32H847.473V620.3H846.473C846.493 619.42 846.873 618.88 847.553 618.72V617.8C846.293 618.08 845.493 619.1 845.493 620.4V622.32ZM842.933 622.32H844.893V620.3H843.913C843.933 619.42 844.313 618.88 844.973 618.72V617.8C843.713 618.08 842.933 619.1 842.933 620.4V622.32ZM858.655 631.04C857.935 631.36 856.875 631.6 855.815 631.6C852.575 631.6 850.695 629.5 850.695 626.24C850.695 622.74 852.775 620.76 855.895 620.76C857.015 620.76 857.935 620.98 858.595 621.28L859.035 619.8C858.575 619.6 857.495 619.24 855.835 619.24C851.655 619.24 848.755 622.06 848.755 626.3C848.755 630.68 851.595 633.14 855.455 633.14C857.095 633.14 858.375 632.82 858.995 632.52L858.655 631.04ZM859.856 623.16L863.416 631.34C863.516 631.54 863.556 631.68 863.556 631.78C863.556 631.9 863.496 632 863.416 632.2C862.996 633.04 862.416 633.58 861.956 633.94C861.416 634.36 860.836 634.64 860.416 634.76L860.956 636.16C861.476 636.02 862.456 635.62 863.236 634.98C864.396 633.96 865.156 632.58 866.416 629.38L869.036 623.16H867.076L865.196 628.38C864.976 629.02 864.816 629.56 864.596 630.1H864.536C864.356 629.56 864.156 629 863.916 628.4L861.856 623.16H859.856ZM869.468 623.24L872.748 627.98L869.328 632.92H871.348L872.708 630.78C873.088 630.2 873.388 629.7 873.708 629.1H873.748C874.088 629.68 874.408 630.22 874.768 630.78L876.188 632.92H878.268L874.888 627.92L878.188 623.24H876.188L874.868 625.28C874.528 625.8 874.208 626.3 873.888 626.86H873.848C873.528 626.32 873.228 625.82 872.868 625.3L871.528 623.24H869.468ZM878.684 623.16L882.244 631.34C882.344 631.54 882.384 631.68 882.384 631.78C882.384 631.9 882.324 632 882.244 632.2C881.824 633.04 881.244 633.58 880.784 633.94C880.244 634.36 879.664 634.64 879.244 634.76L879.784 636.16C880.304 636.02 881.284 635.62 882.064 634.98C883.224 633.96 883.984 632.58 885.244 629.38L887.864 623.16H885.904L884.024 628.38C883.804 629.02 883.644 629.56 883.424 630.1H883.364C883.184 629.56 882.984 629 882.744 628.4L880.684 623.16H878.684ZM888.836 632.92H890.536L890.776 628.38C890.836 627.34 890.896 626.06 890.916 624.9H890.976C891.236 625.8 891.636 627.22 891.956 628.12L893.636 632.88H894.976L896.796 628.04C897.336 626.54 897.596 625.78 897.876 624.9H897.916C897.956 626.06 898.036 627.32 898.076 628.34L898.316 632.92H900.056L899.376 623.24H897.096L895.576 627.42C895.196 628.48 894.676 629.98 894.436 630.7H894.416C894.176 629.92 893.796 628.76 893.536 628.06L891.816 623.24H889.556L888.836 632.92ZM908.927 631.2C908.447 631.42 907.767 631.66 906.807 631.66C904.887 631.66 903.487 630.32 903.487 628.08C903.487 626.1 904.687 624.48 906.847 624.48C907.807 624.48 908.447 624.72 908.867 624.94L909.287 623.52C908.807 623.26 907.867 623.02 906.847 623.02C903.647 623.02 901.627 625.2 901.627 628.18C901.627 631.14 903.527 633.14 906.447 633.14C907.747 633.14 908.787 632.8 909.247 632.58L908.927 631.2ZM911.272 623.24V632.92H913.112V628.7H913.432C915.032 628.7 915.932 629.4 916.572 630.94C916.872 631.76 917.192 632.52 917.472 632.92H919.392C918.932 632.14 918.612 631.18 918.352 630.54C917.592 628.8 916.672 627.78 915.112 627.6L919.312 623.24H917.072L913.492 627.44H913.112V623.24H911.272ZM920.88 623.24V632.92H923.02C924.02 631.24 925.06 629.4 925.96 627.88C926.52 626.92 926.92 626.16 927.54 624.92H927.58C927.5 626.52 927.46 627.3 927.46 628.88V632.92H929.22V623.24H927.06L924.12 628.2C923.46 629.32 923.16 630 922.56 631.18L922.5 631.16C922.58 629.76 922.62 628.8 922.62 627.24V623.24H920.88ZM939.873 628.46C939.933 628.24 939.953 627.96 939.953 627.6C939.953 625.78 939.093 623.02 935.933 623.02C933.073 623.02 931.353 625.36 931.353 628.26C931.353 631.16 933.153 633.14 936.133 633.14C937.673 633.14 938.753 632.8 939.413 632.52C939.293 632.08 939.213 631.64 939.093 631.22C938.413 631.48 937.653 631.7 936.393 631.7C934.653 631.7 933.173 630.74 933.113 628.46H939.873ZM933.133 627.14C933.273 625.94 934.033 624.34 935.793 624.34C937.353 624.34 937.933 625.48 938.073 626.42C938.153 626.66 938.173 626.92 938.173 627.12V627.14H933.133ZM943.312 618.7H941.332V620.72H942.332C942.312 621.6 941.932 622.14 941.252 622.3V623.22C942.512 622.94 943.312 621.9 943.312 620.62V618.7ZM945.852 618.7H943.912V620.72H944.892C944.872 621.6 944.492 622.14 943.832 622.3V623.22C945.092 622.94 945.852 621.9 945.852 620.62V618.7Z"
                              fill="white"/>
                    </g>
                </g>
            </g>
        </g>
        <defs>
            <pattern id="pattern0" patternContentUnits="objectBoundingBox" width="1" height="1">
                <use xlink:href="#image0" transform="translate(0 0.0204) scale(0.0027933)"/>
            </pattern>
            <linearGradient id="paint0_linear" x1="642" y1="790" x2="642" y2="637" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
                <stop/>
                <stop offset="1" stop-opacity="0"/>
            </linearGradient>
            <clipPath id="clip0">
                <rect width="22" height="22" fill="white" transform="translate(762 664)"/>
            </clipPath>
            <clipPath id="clip1">
                <rect width="22" height="22" fill="white" transform="translate(731 521)"/>
            </clipPath>
            <clipPath id="clip2">
                <rect width="22" height="22" fill="white" transform="translate(812 311)"/>
            </clipPath>
            <clipPath id="clip3">
                <rect width="22" height="22" fill="white" transform="translate(488 678)"/>
            </clipPath>
            <clipPath id="clip4">
                <rect width="22" height="22" fill="white" transform="translate(496 467)"/>
            </clipPath>
            <clipPath id="clip5">
                <rect width="22" height="22" fill="white" transform="translate(487 271)"/>
            </clipPath>
            <image id="image0" data-name="6.png" width="358" height="349"
                   xlink:href="https://avatanplus.com/files/resources/original/575c3d75994521554050137c.png"/>
        </defs>
    </svg>

</div>
```

Comment: все правильно, работает transform в svg, коордиеаты точек в фигурах масштабируются относительно начала координат

Comment: а есть ли способ из центра <rect/> делать масштабирование?

Comment: конечно, способов 2, один нормальный, но надо заново рисовать, второй : сначала translate(-x,-y)scale(1.1)translate(x,y), где xy это координаты центра

Comment: а нормальный способ - сразу нарисовать все элементы с центром в начале координат, поместить их в группы и группы уже двигать, тогда scale будет применяться без фокусов

Comment: А координаты центра... Их откуда взять? Они на самом <rect/> указаны?

Comment: на глаз =) или посчитать, вы опубликуйте нерабочий пример в вопросе =]

Comment: Последний вопрос, если можно, и иду проверять) transform-origin в таком случае, должен быть выставлен в 0 0?

Comment: он не играет роли в svg, насколько мне известно

Comment: Слушай, ты не знаешь, в Figma можно сделать то о чем ты говоришь, про нормальный способ? transform-origin работает, но с scale он работает просто ужасно.

Comment: я просто мог бы изменить ошибочный код, а вот с нуля писать мне лень...

Comment: Я могу тебе скинуть архив? Мне бы прост принцип понять

Comment: в вопрос можно добавить пример кода, который будет выполняться прямо на сранице - очень удобно,там кнопочка есть

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Способов 2:

1. Изначально позиционировать элементы относительно начала координат, помещать их в группы и уже группы позиционировать на холсте при `transform=translate` группы.
2. Применять масштабирование следующим образом:

   ```
   transform=translate(-cx,-cy)scale(1.2)translate(cx,cy)
   ```

где `cx,cy` - это координаты центра, вокруг которого будет происходить масштабирование

Что касается Вашего примера:

Я убрал то что посчитал лишним из css и svg изменил вот это

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.block {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  svg {
    width: 100%
  }
```

```html
<svg width="1440" height="790" viewBox="0 0 1440 790" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
        <style>
            #item6 {
              cursor:pointer;
              transition: all .2s;
            }
            #item6:hover {
                transform:scale(1.2);
            }
        </style>
        <rect width="1440" height="790" fill="none"></rect>
        <rect id="dark" width="1440" height="790" fill="black" fill-opacity="0.5"></rect>
        <rect id="dark-bottom" y="637" width="1440" height="153" fill="url(#paint0_linear)"></rect>
        <g id="birthday">
            <g id="group6">
                <g transform="translate(1194.5, 665.5)">
                  <rect id="item6" x="-122.5" y="-124.5" 
                        width="245" height="249" fill="url(#pattern0)"></rect>
                </g>
                <g id="info_6" pointer-events="none">
                    <g id="arrow6">
                        <path id="line6" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M760 653.5C760 652.395 760.895 651.5 762 651.5H1023.28L1206.56 704.579C1207.62 704.886 1208.23 705.995 1207.92 707.056C1207.61 708.117 1206.5 708.728 1205.44 708.421L1022.72 655.5H762C760.895 655.5 760 654.605 760 653.5Z" fill="white"></path>
                        <path id="ellipse6" d="M1222 706.5C1222 715.613 1214.61 723 1205.5 723C1196.39 723 1189 715.613 1189 706.5C1189 697.387 1196.39 690 1205.5 690C1214.61 690 1222 697.387 1222 706.5Z" fill="#F32121"></path>
                        <path id="ellipseStroke6" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M1205.5 692.5C1197.77 692.5 1191.5 698.768 1191.5 706.5C1191.5 714.232 1197.77 720.5 1205.5 720.5C1213.23 720.5 1219.5 714.232 1219.5 706.5C1219.5 698.768 1213.23 692.5 1205.5 692.5ZM1186.5 706.5C1186.5 696.007 1195.01 687.5 1205.5 687.5C1215.99 687.5 1224.5 696.007 1224.5 706.5C1224.5 716.993 1215.99 725.5 1205.5 725.5C1195.01 725.5 1186.5 716.993 1186.5 706.5Z" fill="white"></path>
                    </g>
                </g>
            </g>
        </g>
        <defs>
            <pattern id="pattern0" patternContentUnits="objectBoundingBox" width="1" height="1">
                <use xlink:href="#image0" transform="translate(0 0.0204) scale(0.0027933)"></use>
            </pattern>
          
            <image id="image0" data-name="6.png" width="358" height="349" xlink:href="https://avatanplus.com/files/resources/original/575c3d75994521554050137c.png"></image>
        </defs>
    </svg>
```

Comment: Блин, очень круто! Спасибо большое! Получается, берутся координаты <rect/>, к ним прибавляется половина размеров элемента, всё это оборачивается в group, и путем задания отрицательных координат, по половине от размера элемента на X и Y, <rect/> находится в центре координат group. Надеюсь правильно понял) Спасибо ещё раз, ты очень крут!

Comment: @НикитаХлыстов все именно так, считать от центра - проще и трансформы работают без танцев с бубном

Answer (score -1):

1)Ставишь на большой контейнер фон картинки БЕЗ блюд!

2)изображения блюд в png либо svg кидаешь в каждый свой div
блоку

```html
<div class="блюдо1"</div>
<div class="блюдо2"</div>
<div class="блюдо3"</div>
<div class="блюдо4"</div>
```

кидаешь position:absolute и вертишь как тебе надо!
3)Затем верстаешь линии(Ну описание блюд) которые исходят от блюд примерно таким же методом пишешь текст и т.д
4)При div:hover кидаешь стили, а по клику скрываешь блок с описанием и показываешь блок с темным фоном opacity ну и все
А что бы блюдо которое ты выбрал оставалось цветным, тебе надо играться с z-index

Comment: Проблема в том, что итоговый результат, должен получится прям таким же, как на видео. Плюс адаптив небольшой. Не разрушится ли абсолютное позиционирование, при изменении масштаба?